# EF Core how to fix may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have three classes

```cs
public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DefaultLanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
    public List<TitleTranslation> TitleTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class TitleTranslation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Title.DefaultLanguage))]
    public List<Title> Titles { get; set; }
    public List<TitleTranslation> TitleTranslations { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework Core says:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TitleTranslations_Titles_TitleId' on table 'TitleTranslations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

To be clear, I didn't use the Fluent API, just conventions.

I want to know why this produces errors, and how to fix it.

Comment: Not all EF features are availlable via conventions (or indeed via annotations), you will have to add something to the `OnModelCreating`. See https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method

Comment: *I'm not using the Fluent API* You'll have to, to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I didn't use Fluent API, not I'm not going to use Fluent API, Sorry if my statement made some misunderstandings, I'm not good at English.